# Изменение HTML файла

Tags: html

Как в HTML сделать возможность редактировать HTML код другого файла? Допустим:

1) "Object" в данном случае является тот самый HTML файл, который нужно отредактировать
2) В текстовом поле "Input" будет текст, который необходимо вставить в HTML файл
3) При нажатии на кнопку "Button", изменения файла будут сохранены

```
<OBJECT id="class" name="class" data="file.htm" width="250" height="850"></OBJECT>
<INPUT id="user" name="user" height="100" maxLength="10"></INPUT>
<BUTTON onclick="" value="Кнопка"></BUTTON>
```

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/233805/ - вот как вариант

Answer (score 1):

[[@Никита___](/users/26009/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0___)](/users/26009/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0___) А вы упертый))) На все ваши предыдущие вопросы ответы сводятся к тому, что вам необходимо  сесть за чтение книг по web программированию. Но вы почему-то решили, что вам это не нужно, и упорно пытаетесь решать задачи, прямо скажем, не уровня "новичок", да и к тому же не путем поиска информации в интернете, подходящей для решения задачи информации, а путем поиска  готового решения на этом форуме. Причем полного решения. Вам надо понять - тут не против помочь решать задачи и возникающие проблемы, НО помогают тем, кто сам что-то делает.